# Magento Module Layout not loading

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Im new to Magento,I have been suck with this problem for a while. I want to create a custom URL for VIP members to login. Im trying to create a new login page with a new module because the login process is not same as default process. My login page is not rendering correctly.

Module download link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3l22y1w8j8_cmFkVnVZcUNzRUE

Point me out with my mistake PLEASE.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have checked and found issues in layout and controller files.  please double check

Comment: Thank You. I will check. any chance you can let me know what it is wrong ?

Comment: Layout file don't have valid close handle. loadlayout function have the argument which don't require etc.

Comment: Following is the code